# extract multiple "td' classes from a table

Tags: html, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a site with many tables on it and I am looping through them and getting the data from all tables and exporting that to a csv file. The issue I have is that each table has multiple 'td' classes and I only want a couple of them but I don't know how to narrow them down to just what I want. 
when I run my current code i get extra parts of the table that I don't want and it makes my csv file very messy.
Here is a snippet of the html code for the page that contains the info I want.

```html
<tr class="table_title">
  <td class="sportPicksBorderL2 tanBg fourleft regular" nowrap="nowrap">
    607 <a class="black" href="/college-basketball/teams/team-page.cfm/team/oakland">OAKLND</a>
  </td>
  <td class="sportPicksBorderL2 tanBg zerocenter regular" nowrap="nowrap">&nbsp;136.5&nbsp;</td>

  <td class="sportPicksBorderL2 tanBg zerocenter regular" nowrap="nowrap">28</td>

  <td class="sportPicksBorderL2 tanBg zerocenter regular" nowrap="nowrap">32</td>


  <td class="sportPicksBorderL2 tanBg zerocenter sub_title_red" nowrap="nowrap">60</td>

  <td class="sportPicksBorderR2 tanBg zerocenter regular" nowrap="nowrap" width="100">Cover: +1.5&nbsp;</td>

</tr>
<tr class="table_title">
  <td class="sportPicksBorderL2 tanBg fourleft regular" nowrap="nowrap">
    608 <a class="black" href="/college-basketball/teams/team-page.cfm/team/youngstown-state">YOUNG</a> <span class="sub_title_red">«</span>
  </td>
  <td class="sportPicksBorderL2 tanBg zerocenter regular" nowrap="nowrap">&nbsp;-2.5&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="sportPicksBorderL2 tanBg zerocenter regular" nowrap="nowrap">24</td>
  <td class="sportPicksBorderL2 tanBg zerocenter regular" nowrap="nowrap">37</td>

  <td class="sportPicksBorderL2 tanBg zerocenter sub_title_red" nowrap="nowrap">61</td>

  <td class="sportPicksBorderR2 tanBg zerocenter regular" nowrap="nowrap" width="100">Under: 121&nbsp;</td>

</tr>
```

Here is what I run to extract my data

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
from requests import get
import pandas as pd
from csv import writer
url = 'https://www.vegasinsider.com/college-basketball/scoreboard/scores.cfm/game_date/01-12-2020'
source = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
tables = soup.find_all('table', attrs={'class': 'sportPicksBorder'})
filename = 'C:\\Users\\mylocation\\Documents\\tables.csv'
with open(filename, 'w')as f:
    data = []
    csv_writer = writer(f)
    for table in tables:
        rows = table.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            columns = row.find_all('td')
            csv_writer.writerow([column.text.strip() for column in columns])
```

what I want is the a class="black"/a this has my team name without a red arrow by it
class=sportPicksBorderL2
class=sportPicksBorderR2

My original code returns these 4 rows for each table.

```
Final Score Score                                                   
Teams   Odds    1   2   T   ATS                                 
847 ARIZNA  -4  31  34  65  Over: 147                                   
848 OREGST Â«   143.5   31  51  82  Cover: +21
```

What I would like to keep from this is.

```
ARIZNA  -4  31  34  65  Over: 147                                   
OREGST 143.5 31 51  82  Cover: +21
```

I want to strip off the Â«, the numbers before the team names, and the first 2 table rows from what I am scraping, but still being a novice in web scraping and python, am I finding it difficult to figure out. If anyone has a good training resource, i'm all ears.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that in my columns loop I needed to format my code in this way to find only the specific 'td' that I wanted

```
columns = row.find_all(class_=["black", "sportPicksBorderL2 tanBg zerocenter regular", "sportPicksBorderL2 tanBg zerocenter sub_title_red", "sportPicksBorderR2 tanBg zerocenter regular"])
```

Using find_all to find all classes then using class_ to look at all those classes to find the ones that wanted, I needed to Comma separate them and then putting them in the order that I want them displayed in my csv file was what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

you want the following:

```
var blacks = document.getElementsByClassName('black');
```

var blacks will be an array and you can access each element as follows:

```
for(i = 0; i< blacks.length;i++){
    var black = blacks[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.

```
from simplified_scrapy.spider import SimplifiedDoc 
html='''
<table class="sportPicksBorder">
 <tr class="table_title">
  <td class="sportPicksBorderL2 tanBg fourleft regular" nowrap="nowrap">
    607 <a class="black" href="/college-basketball/teams/team-page.cfm/team/oakland">OAKLND</a>
  </td>
  <td class="sportPicksBorderL2 tanBg zerocenter regular" nowrap="nowrap">&nbsp;136.5&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="sportPicksBorderL2 tanBg zerocenter regular" nowrap="nowrap">28</td>
  <td class="sportPicksBorderL2 tanBg zerocenter regular" nowrap="nowrap">32</td>
  <td class="sportPicksBorderL2 tanBg zerocenter sub_title_red" nowrap="nowrap">60</td>
  <td class="sportPicksBorderR2 tanBg zerocenter regular" nowrap="nowrap" width="100">Cover: +1.5&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table_title">
  <td class="sportPicksBorderL2 tanBg fourleft regular" nowrap="nowrap">
    608 <a class="black" href="/college-basketball/teams/team-page.cfm/team/youngstown-state">YOUNG</a> <span class="sub_title_red">«</span>
  </td>
  <td class="sportPicksBorderL2 tanBg zerocenter regular" nowrap="nowrap">&nbsp;-2.5&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="sportPicksBorderL2 tanBg zerocenter regular" nowrap="nowrap">24</td>
  <td class="sportPicksBorderL2 tanBg zerocenter regular" nowrap="nowrap">37</td>
  <td class="sportPicksBorderL2 tanBg zerocenter sub_title_red" nowrap="nowrap">61</td>
  <td class="sportPicksBorderR2 tanBg zerocenter regular" nowrap="nowrap" width="100">Under: 121&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html) # create doc
tables = doc.getElementsByClass('sportPicksBorder')
# If you only want to include 'td' of 'a' and remove the arrow at the back, you can do this
for table in tables:
    rows = table.trs
    for row in rows:
        column = row.td # Get the first td
        column.removeElement('span') # Delete that arrow
        print (column.text)
        # You can do the same
        print (column.firstText(),column.a.text)
```

Result:

```
607 OAKLND
607 OAKLND
608 YOUNG
608 YOUNG
```

Here are more examples:https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/blob/master/doc_examples/

Comment: I guess i'm a little confused by this answer, The python script that I was using worked fine it was just returning more data than I wanted because of how the tables are designed on the web page. Each table has 4 tr's in it and I only want the td from 2 of those. The td in each row has it's own td class and the way my code works now it captures all the the td from all 4 tr's and I want to only capture the data from 2 of those. How can I accomplish this with my current code which works fine just returns more data than I want.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with BeautifulSoup, so I don't know how to filter and extract the data you want with BeautifulSoup.